# Is it correct to say that this series diverge in the given annulus?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, solution-verification, laurent-series

> Let's consider the annulus $1\le|z|\le2$ and $$f(z)=\frac{2z+3}{z^2+3z+2}$$
>   Find its Laurent series.

First I simplify the expresion:
$$f(z)=\frac{2z+3}{(z+1)(z+2)}=(2z+3)\left(\frac1{z+1}-\frac1{z+2}\right)
\\= \frac{2z+3}{z+1}-\frac{2z+3}{z+2}=\frac1{z+1}+2-\left(2-\frac1{z+2}\right)
\\=\frac1{z+1} +\frac1{z+2}=f_1(z)+f_2(z)$$

I say the series representation of $f$ diverges in $1\le|z|\le2$, since both $f_1,f_2$ are geometric series, and those diverge when $|z|\ge1$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\dfrac1{z+1}=\dfrac{\frac1{z}}{1-(-\frac1{z})}$, and $\dfrac1{z+2}=\dfrac{\frac1{2}}{1-(-\frac{z}{2})}$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, just one more question, this is only true if the annulus is $1<|z|<2$ instead of $1\le|z|\le2$, right? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Well the Laurent series converges everywhere inside the anulus, but on the boundary it is not so clear. Please see [Convergent Laurent Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series#Convergent_Laurent_series).